# Can rust slice type [T] be used without reference or pointer?

Tags: rust, types, slice, literals

The line assigning arguably a slice literal

```rust
let integers: [i32] = [ 1, 2, 3 ][..];
```

gives a message that `integers` “doesn't have a size known at compile-time”. Why is it not obvious that storage space is needed for three `i32` and one `usize`? Is my thinking wrong or why can the compiler not see this?

Probably related is https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/slice.html saying “Slice types are generally used through pointer types.” My guess is that this general rule is enforced that the current compiler simply disallows uses of slice without indirection, but the associated compiler message is misleading; so type policy, not size is at the core of the problem here. (From @colonel-thirty-two's answer [In Rust, why is '[T]' and 'str' slice type not a syntax error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67125730/in-rust-why-is-t-and-str-slice-type-not-a-syntax-error) I learn that this may possibly change in not so near future.)

I also note that https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/primitives/array.html does not discuss [T], but &[T].

Comment: Because putting your title into the search is apparently too hard: [Why does Rust not allow slice as a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63793937/why-does-rust-not-allow-slice-as-a-value) [What does "Sized is not implemented" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28044231/what-does-sized-is-not-implemented-mean) [What is a "fat pointer"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57754901/what-is-a-fat-pointer)

Comment: @cafce25 search may yield different results at different times. If I put the title in the search, as you suggest, I get: ”We couldn't find anything for can rust slice type be used without reference or pointer tagged t“; thank you for the links, but it is hard to see for me how they relate to my question about the ability of the compiler to calculate the size of the given literal. I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63181846/why-is-rust-telling-unknown-size-at-compile-time-instead-of-another-error-in-a as closer issue, but I think it is about assignment of a non-literal into a slice.

Comment: I think I have found an answer to the question here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63793937/why-does-rust-not-allow-slice-as-a-value], difference being an intermediate step via variable `let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rust uses types to convey information it has at compile time. Indeed, if you were to let Rust infer the type if `[1, 2, 3]`, it would tell you it's a `[i32; 3]`, and everything would work fine. By coercing `[i32; 3]` into `[i32]`, you force the compiler to lose the information about the size of the array.

Besides, note that `[1, 2, 3]` does *not* store three `i32` and a `usize`, but just three `i32`. Rust makes the (very reasonable) choice of storing the size of unsized types (as well as other information, if required) alongside pointers to that data, not within that data. This allows arbitrary slicing without copying any data. These pointers, in Rust, are called "[fat pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57754901/what-is-a-fat-pointer)".

Finally, unsized types are not necessarily behind pointers. For instance, if you were to create a struct, its last field can be an unsized type:

```rust
struct A {
    x: i32,
    y: [i32],
}
```

the reason for this peculiar restriction is that unsized types is not a finished feature, and since there isn't much pressure for completing it, it will probably stay in this half-baked state for some time.

Besides, rust currently doesn't allow values stored on the stack (which includes variables) to have unsized types, but it's only a temporary limitation, and there is a [WIP feature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/unsized-locals.html) to remove this limitation.

Also, unsized types are somehow unique to Rust. In most other typed languages, there is no such thing. All types *must* have a size defined at compile time or (as in C, for instance), types whose size is not known cannot be instantiated at all.